# Query to find if a folder exists

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have this query which attempts to find this record (which I know exists) in the `AllDocs` table within a Sharepoint content database:

The record has these values

```
DirName:     /MYSITE/MYLIST/A_FOLDER
LeafName:    B_FOLDER
```

So the URL looks like:  `/MYSITE/MYLIST/A_FOLDER/B_FOLDER`

Here's the method I'm trying to write:

```
public bool CheckFolderExist(string folderPath)
{
    var pathArray = folderPath.Split('/');
    string folderName = pathArray.Last(); //The 'LeafName' part...

    var temp = pathArray.Take(pathArray.Length - 1);
    string folderOnly = string.Join("/", temp); //The 'DirName' part...

    CamlQuery cq = new CamlQuery();
    string query = @"<View>
                         <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
                         <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <And>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                                            <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
                                            <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                </And>
                            </Where>
                         </Query>
                       </View>";

    query = string.Format(query, folderName, folderOnly);
    cq.ViewXml = query;

    //_accountList is initiated somewhere else for the moment, and it doesn't seem to be the problem for now...
    ListItemCollection colFolder = _accountList.GetItems(cq);
    _ctx.Load(colFolder);
    _ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (colFolder.Count == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

My method always returns false. I can only think of me perhaps using the wrong field names in the CAML query.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up correcting the CAML query for this:

```
string query = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>
                                                <And>
                                                        <Eq>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                                                            <Value Type='Text'>1</Value>
                                                        </Eq>
                                                        <Eq>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
                                                            <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                                        </Eq>
                                                </And>
                                            </Where></Query></View>";
```